# How to watch only a single field in an object in useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
export const LocaleProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { locale: DEFAULT_LOCALE });

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedLocale = getStoredLocale();
    if (storedLocale) dispatch(changeLocale(storedLocale));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { locale: currentLocale } = state;
    saveLocale(currentLocale);
  }, [state, state.locale]);

  return (
    <LocaleContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </LocaleContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

How to watch only a single field in an object, state. As you can see in the second effect, when I watch only [state.locale] my VS code shows an eslint warning(react-hook/exhaustive-deps), React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'state'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. When I save my code VS code adds state in the dependencies array ([state, state.locale]).

Comment: Why are you calling use `useEffect` twice?

Comment: @IndrekLasn they perform 2 different side effects..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `react-hook/exhaustive-deps` is not smart enough to recognize that only some properties of an object are needed, it focuses on a list of dependee variables (those used inside the `useEffect`), so we can cooperate with the rule by extracting a variable:

```
const { locale: currentLocale } = state;
useEffect(() => {
  saveLocale(currentLocale);
}, [currentLocale]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes because you're utilizing the state variable inside the `useEffect` function. This warning can only go if you don't directly utilize the state variable for anything.

One way to do this and also optimize this code further would be to use `useCallback/useMemo`. Check out the following code:

```
export const LocaleProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { locale: DEFAULT_LOCALE });

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedLocale = getStoredLocale();
    if (storedLocale) dispatch(changeLocale(storedLocale));
  }, []);

  const getCurrentLocale = useCallback(() => state.locale, [state.locale])

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentLocale = getCurrentLocale();
    saveLocale(currentLocale);
  }, [getCurrentLocale]);

  return (
    <LocaleContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </LocaleContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

With the above code, you get to limit the dependencies as you wanted.